# Why doesn't calling Task<T>.Result deadlock?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock, dotnet-httpclient

After reading [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) post a few months ago, I became paranoid of getting the `Result` of a `Task<T>` and incessantly wrapped all of my calls to it with a `ConfigureAwait(false)` or `Task.Run`. However, for some reason the following code completes successfully:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arrays = DownloadMany();

    foreach (var array in arrays);
}

IEnumerable<byte[]> DownloadMany()
{
    string[] links = { "http://google.com", "http://microsoft.com", "http://apple.com" };

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        foreach (var uri in links)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Still here!");
            yield return client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri).Result; // Why doesn't this deadlock?
        }
    }
}
```

The code prints `Still here!` 3 times and then exits. Is this specific to `HttpClient` that it is safe to call `Result` on (as in the people who wrote it have peppered it with `ConfigureAwait(false)`)?

Comment: by the way.. it's much simpler to not block and use await where needed than using `ConfigureAwait` everywhere.

Comment: @i3arnon True, but I'm writing an API that supports both synchronous and asynchronous callers.

Comment: @JamesKo: I recommend that asynchronous methods expose asynchronous APIs. However, if you *must* support both sync and async (e.g., for backwards compatibility), then you may find my recent [MSDN article on brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Task.Result` will only block in the presence of certain `SynchronizationContext`s. In console apps there isn't one so continuations are scheduled on the `ThreadPool`. Just like they are when you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

In UI threads for example there is one that schedules continuations to the single UI thread. If you wait synchronously with `Task.Result` using the UI thread, on a task that can only complete on the UI thread, you've got a deadlock.

Moreover, a deadlock depends on the implementation of `GetByteArrayAsync`. You can only deadlock if it's an async method and its awaits don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

If you want to you can use Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) that adds an appropriate `SynchronizationContext` to your console app to test whether your code can block in UI apps (or ASP.Net).

---

About `HttpClient`'s (and most of .NET's) Task-returning methods: they aren't technically async. They don't use the `async` and `await` keywords. They simply return a task. Usually a wrapper over `Task.Factory.FromAsync`. So it's probably "safe" blocking them anyway.

Comment: This is very strange. I thought this only applied to async/await. There is no continuation here, so I don't understand what would be scheduled on a different thread. Moreover, if the `Result` *isn't* blocking, as you suggest, what is the method returning? Empty arrays?

Comment: @Asad Result is blocking. It's just not blocking the single UI thread (because this isn't a UI app). It's blocking the main thread.

Comment: @i3arnon It isn't clear what UI thread you're talking about. My point is that the `Result` will always be blocking, regardless of the synchronization context available. If the method returns a `Task` of something, that something must be resolved before the getter of `Task.Result` will return a value to you. Whether this is running in a UI app or a console app is immaterial, to my understanding at least.

Comment: @Asad in UI apps (winforms, wpf) there's a single UI thread that can interact with the UI. If any other thread does that it will get an exception. The SC makes sure the continuations run on that thread.

Comment: @i3arnon Ok, but how is this relevant to the current situation? A UI app will behave the same way as a console application when you access `.Result`, i.e. execution will pause and wait synchronously for the Task to complete and the getter of `Result` to return (or raise an exception). The synchronization context won't matter.

Comment: @Asad Task.Result blocks anyway. But if the UI thread is blocked, and it's waiting for itself then it's a deadlock. A block that can never be unblocked.

Comment: The key here is that if you call Result on an asynchronous method that is on the UI thread and doesn't use ConfigureAwait(false). So the UI thread is blocking on an async call that is waiting for the UI thread to be come free before returning.

Comment: @Asad A UI app **will not** behave the same way. A UI app may deadlock, but a console app will not.